Why can't Voyager 1 finally "settle down" to a stable attitude, without needing "40 short puffs per day"?
CNN's September 16, 2024 47-year-old Voyager 1 spacecraft just fired up thrusters it hasn’t used in decades gives a short review of changes from one set of thrusters to another for each of the Voyagers as background. This is due to very slow clogging of propellant lines apparently caused by unexpected "silicon dioxide, a byproduct of the fuel tank’s rubber diaphragm aging".
But I was surprised to read:

Now, the spacecraft is traveling on an unchanging path away from our solar system, so it just requires one set of thrusters to help keep its antenna pointed at Earth. To fuel the thrusters, liquid hydrazine is converted into gas and released in about 40 short puffs per day to keep Voyager 1 oriented correctly.

It's hard to imagine torques at 24 billion kilometers from the Sun in interstellar space so significant that an active control system would be needed to constantly work to compensate them.
And if there's a diaphragm, I wouldn't expect unpredictable "sloshing" of propellant.
To maintain communication with Earth, Voyager 1 simply needs to maintain its dish pointed at the Sun, since at this distance, the Earth never deviates by more than about 0.4 degrees from the Sun. And since Voyager 1 is so far away and traveling in a direction only 4 degrees away from its vector from the Sun, the direction of the Sun from Voyager will be changing very slowly now.
Question: Why can't Voyager 1 finally "settle down" to a stable attitude, without needing "40 short puffs per day"?
Related and with potentially helpful answers:

Could the Voyager spacecraft be spin-stabilized to keep their high gain antennas pointing towards the Sun (and therefore Earth)?
How much do the Voyagers' attitudes drift over time? How often are their thrusters used for attitude control? currently unanswered, if CNN's "40 short puffs per day" is true, then perhaps that's the answer?
Voyager 1's tape recorder and other angular momentum management issues
Did the designers of Voyager neglect the angular momentum of the tape recorders?
What does it mean when the Voyagers "switch thrusters"?
How are Voyager's 16 thrusters oriented? Table that enumerates them and specifies directions quantitatively
How are the Voyagers' thrusters configured in a novel way to minimize accelerations along Earth-spacecraft axis?
How do Voyager 1's Trajectory Control Thrusters differ from its Attitude Control Thrusters?


Background info lifted from How well can Voyager 1 separate Earth signals from Solar noise these days? which is a little bit old now but isn't so far off.

above: data for the Sun, planets, Pluto, Voyager 1 and Voyager 2, from January 1, 1969 (a good year to start things) until now. Dots are now. Data is from NASA JPL Horizons.

above: Angular separation between the earth and the sun in degrees, as seen from Voyager 1 (heavy, blue) and Voyager 2 (light, green). The dips to near-zero stop happening once the spacecraft left the plane of the ecliptic.

from DESCANSO Design and Performance Summary Series Article 4: Voyager Telecommunications as discussed in this answer.

I mean, back in the late 1970's I may have needed "40 short puffs per day" to settle down as well, but I've managed to converge on a natural equilibrium, so I wonder, after all this time, why Voyager hasn't been able to as well.

How accurately can the spacecraft determine its own angular velocity? It can't steady itself perfectly, and there's no rotational friction to stabilize it. If it's pitching or yawing at as little as 0.00023 degrees per second, after 2160 seconds (1/40 of a day) it will be 0.5 degrees off angle and the X-band won't be on target.

@RussellBorogove we know it's got some way to get information about its attitude, and it's probably got some kind of clock - not all control algorithms need separate velocity inputs. But I don't know exactly what information Voyager 1 has these days with so many things shut down. The identical Voyager spacecraft use three-axis-stabilized guidance systems that use gyroscopic and accelerometer inputs to their attitude control computers to point their high-gain antennas towards the Earth

I'd guess it all comes down to small errors, there'll be some error in its attitude measurement, then there'll be some error in the calculations for attitude correction then some more error in the thruster firing. Therefore it'll never quite manage to get into the perfect steady attitude so will need constant corrections

If designing it today with that goal in mind I can imagine installing some very small thrusters, maybe cold gas, which would give them much finer granularity in thruster firings, a tiny amount of thrust on the larger mass of the spacecraft. And maybe three or so star sensor cameras pointed in different directions. And then an internal closed loop computer attitude adjustment algorithm using a clock to measure drift rate in any axis. Using short thruster firings since they aren't in a hurry. It would add some weight, so they would have to decide if it's "worth its weight" in propellant savings.

@StevePemberton well, that's basically what they have! Clearly those "puffs" are rather tiny, seeing as it has been doing 40/day of them for decades and not run out of fuel yet. And I don't think they would have cut on hydrazine even if they had had more efficient thrusters for this late part of the mission, because they would have wanted a generous buffer for the much more substantial course corrections while navigating between the planets (it was far more important to get that right). Regardless, no matter how tiny the attitude corrections there will always be some residual spin.

@leftaroundabout - "no matter how tiny the attitude corrections there will always be some residual spin" sure but I am not talking about "infinite" stillness (if that is the correct terminology, and disregarding gravitational influences). And I am not suggesting replacing the existing thrusters used for course corrections. I am talking about reducing the amount of spin from what the current amount is which requires daily corrections. I'm not saying it made sense for Voyager, or even for future vehicles, I'm saying it should be possible with small thrusters firing for milliseconds.

If my back-of-the-envelope math is correct, an 8 ms pulse from a Voyager thruster (which may or may not be the minimum duty cycle for that model of thruster) should impart something on the order of 0.0005 degrees per second of rotation. Half of that would be the average residual, which is pretty close to the figure I got above for 0.5 degree in 1/40 day.

@StevePemberton JPL and Aerojet have looked into tuning up the MR-103 for a shorter pulse time, which seems more appealing than adding a separate set of thrusters.

@RussellBorogove - Yes the more efficient the existing thrusters can be made, the less the fuel savings potential of building in additional "micro thrusters", making it harder to justify the additional weight and complexity. Although I suspect part of what happens in some cases is that things just need to be efficient enough to meet the mission objectives, with plenty of margin, at which point they don't really need to add more complexity to eke out a little more efficiency. In which case we don't know what more might have been done.


Why can't Voyager 1 finally "settle down" to a stable attitude, without needing "40 short puffs per day"?

Because that would be impossible given the spacecraft design.
The attitude thrusters on the Voyager spacecraft have a minimum on time of 15 ms (some claim 8 ms). The low-level thruster controllers are fairly high rate digital controllers. The valve that feeds the thruster is commanded to be open or closed for the duration of each fixed duration thruster controller time step. Intermediate levels of thruster timing are not achievable. Intermediate levels of thrust are not achievable as the valve is either open or closed.
The Voyager spacecraft use phase plane control, described in this answer. There's inevitably an overcorrection or undercorrection with regard to that  control. That's okay because phase plane control has a drift channel. Those imperfect control issues (which are inevitable) will be dealt with later when the attitude / attitude rate drift out of the drift channel.
One little puff every 36 minutes isn't bad. It is instead rather propellant efficient. Phase plane control has been around since the Apollo era, in part because it is fuel efficient, in part because it works nicely with a digitally-limited thruster controller, and in part because it is easy to show robustness, stability, and all kinds of other "-ilities" that control engineers fuss about.

I cant find a reference for it any longer, but I recall that after the planetary phase was over, they went back to thrusters still on the ground and tested them to find the actual shortest pulse at which they wouldn't malfunction. Then the vehicles started using that timing.   So if 15ms is the "safe" design minimum, that could explain the discrepancy.

@BowlOfRed I ran across that, too, when I was writing this answer. I've closed the gazillion of tabs I had opened to research this answer. It's a bit irrelevant, however, whether the minimum impulse bit is 15 ms or 4 ms or whatever as the vehicles still use phase plane controllers. There's no way to issue a "stop rotation" command in the dead center of the drift channel; that's not a part of phase plane control.

"The Voyager spacecraft use phase plane control..." While I've never, ever seen you write something about spaceflight that wasn't correct, it would be great to read about that somewhere. Maybe I can ask separately. The other thing that I still have not found out is how each set of thrusters is positioned and oriented. If there were two each (back-to-back) that implemented pure pitch, roll, and yaw, then nulling rotation would be impossible for the reason you explain here. But if not, there could be a way to slowly walk the rotation vector to 0.

...or at least a smaller value. In that case the answer would be "there's no need to" rather than "they can't". (i.e. if it ain't broke, don't fix it) Also Could the Voyager spacecraft be spin-stabilized to keep their high gain antennas pointing towards the Sun (and therefore Earth)? seems only to be answered with "if it ain't broke...".

@uhoh - "If it ain't broke don't fix it" is exactly right. The RTGs might last another decade, and that is a mighty big might. The hydrazine should last until 2040, but it will freeze without sufficient RTG warming. Why fix something that ain't broke  is the key. It is the inevitable decline of the RTGs that will mark the end of the vehicle rather than the thrusters.

@uhoh I've looked and looked for details/algorithms on how the Voyager spacecraft performed attitude control. No such luck. Those were the days of "security through obscurity", or even worse, security through not publishing. That said, I have yet to see a spacecraft whose only attitude control is via digitally-controlled thrusters with a fixed orientation relative to the spacecraft and with a minimum on-time (minimum impulse bit) and minimum off-time that did not use phase plane control. I encountered many spacecraft over my career, and those with fixed thrusters invariably used phase plane.

@DavidHammen Thank you for doing a deep dive on the Voyagers. I'm certainly convinced now in principle at least. Whoever designed those incredibly reliable valves must take great satisfaction in knowing that so far away in such an extreme environment, they're still doing their thing. fyi I've just asked Understanding the shape of the trajectory in this simplified phase plane control diagram - continuous thrust or impulses?


It's hard to imagine torques at 24 billion kilometers from the Sun in interstellar space so significant that an active control system would be needed to constantly work to compensate them.

You don't really have to compensate for external torque, you have to compensate for the residual rotation left after thrust.
Voyager has no appreciable drag in rotation.  Both the sensors that detect attitude and attitude rates and the thrusters that correct them have errors.  So any attempt to completely stop the rotation leaves some error that will accumulate over time to move the antenna out of alignment if uncorrected.

This answer could be improved by citing sources.  Furthermore, while it's an adequate and plausible explanation for why a "stable" (per the question) attitude is unachievable (there is no natural restoring force), it does not explain the particular rate of correction burns (40/day).  Is that primarily due to sensor inaccuracies or burn impulse imprecision?  And is the impact of interstellar wind on the large antenna dish truly insignificant in comparison to intrinsic control issues?  Since passing the heliopause, the prevailing wind is no longer aligned with the spacecraft's travel direction.

The moon stays with the same point pointed towards the earth, without any puffing.  I don't claim to understand how that works, but isn't that a counterexample disproving "any attempt to completely stop the rotation leaves some error that will accumulate over time to move the antenna out of alignment if uncorrected"?  Might voyager be able to use the same kind of phenomenon the moon uses?  Or maybe something else? (e.g. some analysis taking solar wind into account, as @ScottMcPeak mentions)

@DonHatch The answer does explain why the Moon is not comparable: it states "Voyager has no appreciable drag in rotation." The Moon has drag with the Earth. So, no the Moon is not a counterexample.

@DonHatch See this answer to How does gravity-gradient stabilization work? where I link to Gravity Gradient Stabilization - APL-03-05-Fischell.pdf and see also  What are damper booms, and how do they facilitate triaxial stabilization? Interstellar space is pretty much frictionless. The diaphragm in the fuel tank prevents sloshing of the propellant, so there's not even any viscous drag.

@DonHatch Without any significant passive damping mechanism (no drag or magnetotorquers), thrusters are all that's available. I'm asking why they can't be used to eventually actively damp residual rotation. The Moon is tidally locked because it is lumpy inside, and as it spun it induced tiny density deformations in the Earth which dissipated energy and pulled back on the Moon's lumps, slowly synchronizing the Moon so that it spun on it's axis at the same rate it rotates round the Earth. The Earth's internal flexibility and internal friction became the damper for the Moon's rotational energy.

I think the point is that, even in the absence of mechanical torques, it is impossible to get you spin to be exactly zero in a vacuum. It's always going to be drifting slowly around one axis or another. While you'd think that you could make the feedback precise enough that you'd be able to maintain the same attitude for months, David Hammen's answer says that they can't apply an arbitrarily small torque.

@DonHatch The Moon does not stay with exactly the same point pointed towards the earth. "The lunar libration in longitude was discovered by Johannes Hevelius in 1648.[3] It can reach 7°54′ in amplitude." from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration
